# How do I share applications windows between OS X and Linux?

Tags: osx, x11

[I originally asked this question over on Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/194492/how-do-i-share-applications-windows-between-os-x-and-linux), but I didn't get any answers.

I'm trying to set up Xdmx on my Macbook Pro and my Ubuntu 10.04 workstation so that I can share my MBP's keyboard and mouse as well as X applications running on the workstation across the laptop display, a laptop attached monitor, and the workstation's monitor.

1. Where do I find the latest Xdmx? The Sourceforge site says that the code there is unmaintained and the project has been merged into Xserver. I can't find an up to date source or binary distribution.
2. How do I install it? Is there a package file? Do I have to build from source?
3. Are there other options for accomplishing what I've described above?

Comment: Are you sure there is a port of xdmx to the Mac? I tried all my Google karma but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 7):

It turns out that trying to run `Xdmx` from the Mac was the wrong approach.  Instead I ran it from the Linux workstation.  The steps to accomplish this are something like the following:

1. Install `xpra` on both systems.
2. Start `xpra` on the Linux workstation and attach to it from the MBP (instructions in the above link).
3. Start one `Xephyr` window on the workstation with `Xephyr :101 &`
4. Start another on the MBP via `Xpra`: `DISPLAY=:13 Xephyr :101 &`
5. Finally, [start `Xdmx` as described here](https://web.archive.org/web/20110225150836/http://intellilinux.info/node/25)

```
Xdmx -configfile xdmx.conf -config clone_config +xinerama -input :100 -input :101 :102&
```

At this point, apps started on `DISPLAY=:102` will show up on both systems, but it's not really usable at this point.  Note that the commands in #3, 4, and 5 are all run on the workstation.

Comment: hi @Matt, Your 5th point is hyper-linked to a web-page, which is no more available, can you add that if you have noted. If you have it, please edit your answer accordingly.